# Write $z=5-5i$ in the polar form with $z=Arg(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Write $z=5-5i$ in the polar form with $z=Arg(z)$

**My work**

Let $z=5-5i\in \mathbb{C}$ then

$r=\sqrt{5^2+5^2}=5\sqrt{2}$

$\theta=tan^{-1}(\frac{-5}{5})=\frac{-\pi}{4}$

By definition, $-\pi<Arg(z)\leq \pi$ then

[image]

I have problem trying to find that angle. Can someone help me?

Comment: You already have the correct answer in $r=5\sqrt2$ and $\theta =-\frac {\pi}4$. What else do you need?

Comment: The angle when $\theta=Arg(z)$ @MohammadZuhairKhan

Comment: I assume you want the angle that fits in $[0,2\pi]$ or atleast that is how I remember I was taught in high-school. Well, remember that $e^{ix}$ has a periodicity of $2\pi$ so  you can just add $2\pi$ to $-\frac{\pi}{4}$ and get the angle you seek. Of course you can also look at your graph and see that you are in the fourth quadrant and well, it's at a distance of $2\pi$ from the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you already finished your work. You found the the module is $5\sqrt{2}$, the argument is $-\frac{\pi}{4}$, so the number is $z=5\sqrt{2}e^{-i\frac{\pi}{4}}=5\sqrt{2}(\cos(-\frac{\pi}{4})+i\sin(-\frac{\pi}{4}))=5\sqrt{2}(\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})-i\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}))$.

Comment: I need the other angle, when $\theta= Arg(z)$, the angle $\theta=\frac{-\pi}{4}$ is when $Arg(z)\not = \theta$

Comment: Didn't you write you need the angle between $-\pi$ and $\pi$? Well, $-\frac{\pi}{4}$ is exactly there. I don't understand the problem.

Comment: I need the principal argument of $z$...

Comment: Yes, the principal argument is the argument in the interval $(-\pi,\pi]$. And indeed we have $-\frac{\pi}{4}\in(-\pi,\pi]$. This is the principal argument.

Comment: Okay, thanks... is a little confused. Thanks